# Encountered an Error Creating a New Git Branch

Tags: git

Where should I start learning Git? I'm looking for resources and YouTube videos to follow.

I attempted to follow a Git tutorial on YouTube to learn the basics. I expected to understand the basic commands and concepts, but I encountered difficulty when trying to create a new branch. I received an error message that I couldn't resolve. Currently, I'm seeking clarification on branching in Git to address this issue.

Comment: You should add to your question what you tried to do (EG what command did you use) and exactly what error you received.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is very open-ended. You could ask an LLM. Or if you have a concrete error you can ask us.

Comment: Also, this piece: "Where should I start learning Git? I'm looking for resources and YouTube videos to follow." is too broad and considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.  You should remove it from your question or you may find that your question will get closed.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic